# Case Study: Singleton class inheritance - Good or bad?

Tags: java, inheritance, singleton

I have an example code of Singleton class inheritance below. However, I've not forseen if there's any hidden issue might happen with this code. Can someone analyze and give me a hint?

```
interface ChairIF {
    public int getLeg();

    public void test();
}

class ChairImpl implements ChairIF {

    private static final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private static ChairIF instance = null;

    public static ChairIF getInstance(String clazzName) {
        //get class by clazzName
        Class clazz = null;
        try {
            clazz = Class.forName(clazzName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new ChairImpl();
                }
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }

        //init singleton instance of clazzName
        if (instance == null) {
            lock.lock();

            try {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = (ChairIF) clazz.newInstance();
                } else {
                    if (instance.getClass() != clazz) {
                        instance = (ChairIF) clazz.newInstance();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                instance = new ChairImpl();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        } else {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                if (!instance.getClass().getName().equals(clazz.getName())) {
                    instance = (ChairIF) clazz.newInstance();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                instance = new ChairImpl();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }


    public int getLeg() {
        return 4;
    }

    public void test() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

class ThreeLegChair extends ChairImpl {
   public ThreeLegChair() {}

   public int getLeg() {
      return 3;
   }

   public void test() {
      int i = 0;

      while(i < 10000) {
         System.out.println("i: " + i++);
      }
   }
}

class NoLegChair extends ChairImpl {
   public NoLegChair() {}

   public int getLeg() {
      return 0;
   }

   public void test() {
      int j = 0;

      while(j < 5000) {
         System.out.println("j: " + j++);
      }
   }
}

public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(ChairImpl.getInstance("ThreeLegChair").getLeg());
     System.out.println(ChairImpl.getInstance("NoLegChair").getLeg());

     /***
     TODO: build logic to run 2 test() simultaneously.
     ChairImpl.getInstance("ThreeLegChair").test();
     ChairImpl.getInstance("NoLegChair").test(); 
     ****/
   }
}
```

As you can see, I did put some test code in 2 subclasses. ThreeLegChair is to loop from 0 to 10000 and print it out. NoLegChair is to loop only from 0 to 5000 and print it out.

The result I got in the console log is correct. ThreeLegChair printed i from 0 to 10000. NoLegChair printed j from 0 to 5000.

Please share me your thought :)

Comment: Nicely worded good example, this should be posted as an example on how to ask a question..

Comment: This ... isn't a singleton.

Comment: (And if it were, you couldn't inherit from it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you post isn't an implementation of the singleton pattern.

Quite simply, you can do:

```
ChairImpl ci = new ChairImpl();
```

And instantiate as many as you want.

The traditional method of implementing the singleton pattern is the make the constructor private, have a private static field that holds the single instance of the class, and a static `getInstance()` method that either instantiates that instance or returns the existing one. Making that threadsafe involves either declaring it `synchronized` or using a locking scheme.

The private constructor bit makes it so you *can't* inherit from it.

That said, in Java the preferred way is using an `enum` which provides all the hard parts for free:

```
public enum MySingleton {
    INSTANCE;

    public int getLeg() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

And using as:

```
MySingleton ms = MySingleton.INSTANCE;
int leg = ms.getLeg();
```

Answer (score 2):

Singleton pattern is achieved using the concept of **private constructor** i.e. the class itself is responsible for creating single instance of the class (singleton) and preventing other classes from creating objects.

Now as the constructor is `private`, **you cannot inherit the singleton class at first place**. **In your case, I do not see a private constructor** which makes it vulnerable to object creation from other classes accessing it.

Singleton pattern examples:

- Using enumerations in Java

> ```
> enum SingletonEnum {
>   SINGLE_INSTANCE;
>   public void doStuff() {
>       System.out.println("Singleton using Enum");
>   }
> }
> ```

- Lazy initialization approach

> class SingletonClass {
>
> ```
>   private static SingletonClass singleInstance;
>
>   private SingletonClass() {
>       // deny access to other classes
>   }
>
>   // The object creation will be delayed until getInstance method is called.
>   public static SingletonClass getInstance() {
>
>       if (null == singleInstance) {
>           // Create only once
>           singleInstance = new SingletonClass();
>       }
>
>       return singleInstance;
>   }
> }
> ```

However, the above example may not guarantee singleton behavior in multithreaded environment. It is recommended to use [double checked locking](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074979/java-concurrency/double-checked-locking--clever--but-broken.html) mechanism to ensure that you have created a single instance of this class.

Comment: In Java the preferred way to implement a singleton is using an `enum` which actually eliminates having to deal with it (Especially the multithreaded part you added in your edit).

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with you Brain.

Comment: @BrianRoach :  have added enum example in my post.

Comment: thank you guys, focus on inheritance, I forgot about the most important thing of singleton :)

Answer (score 0):

Singletons usually have private constructor. Your class is not following proper Singleton pattern. otherwise you would not be inherit your singleton class.